# Dial Pad Form with Input Mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have pieced together a dial pad form which when clicking on the form buttons will add values to a text field, intended to be a phone number. I am trying to add a mask to the text field to be formatted as a number such as (123) 456-7890, but can't seem to get it working when clicking the buttons (only works on key press). Is there a way to force the field to be formatted as a number?

Can't seem to get the mask working here but there is a live example:
http://www.aljphoto.com/dialpad/testmask.html

```js
var phoneScreen = $("#phone"); var phoneNumber = phoneScreen.val();
var delBtn = $("#del"); var clrBtn = $("#clr");
var numBtn = $(".number");

numBtn.click(function() {
    var number = $(this).val();
  updatePhoneNumber(number);
  printPhoneNumber();
});
delBtn.click(function() {
    deleteNumber();
  printPhoneNumber();
});
clrBtn.click(function() {
    clearNumber();
  printPhoneNumber();
});

function updatePhoneNumber(newNumber) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber + newNumber;
}
function deleteNumber() {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.slice(0,-1);
}
function clearNumber() {
    phoneNumber = "";
}
function printPhoneNumber() {
    phoneScreen.val(phoneNumber);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://forkcast.io/loyalty/pizza-republic/js/jquery.SimpleMask.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post" id="form">
 <input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" style="height:50px;width:250px;margin:5px;font-size:20px;padding-left:5px;"/>
<br /><br />
<button type="button" class="number" value="1">1</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="number" value="2">2</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="number" value="3">3</button>
<br />
<button type="button" type="button" class="number" value="4">4</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="number" value="5">5</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="number" value="6">6</button>
<br />
<button type="button" type="button" class="number" value="7">7</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="number" value="8">8</button>
<button type="button" type="button" class="number" value="9">9</button>
<br />
<button type="button" id="del" class="del" value="del" style="">&nbsp;</button>
<button type="button" class="number" value="0">0</button>
<input type="submit" id="dial" value="GO"/>

</form>
```